# A Riddle for me

Tags: riddle

> When I'm low you cannot speak
>
> When I’m high you'll be drunk with power
>
> What am I?

Hint:

> Your answer may increase me

Hint:

> I affect you all

Comment: It's usually better to wait awhile before adding hints.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the tip. In learning mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it

> reputation ?

Since

> When I'm low you cannot speak

And

> Low reputation means you can't comment or join the chat room

Also

> When I’m high you'll be drunk with power

And

> High rep users gain power over how the site runs